# Playwright NUnit - Verify all response headers within custom Attribute

Tags: .net, nunit, playwright

I'm attempting to create a custom attribute I can assign to certain tests to verify header information for ALL responses received during that test. It seems that the FetchAsync function is causing the request to be altered as well as it is causing internal server errors on API calls that work otherwise.

```
public class CheckHeadersAttribute : Attribute, ITestAction
{
    public async void BeforeTest(ITest test)
    {
        var testState = (PageTest?)test.Parent?.Fixture;

        if (testState == null) 
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot resolve test state to preconfigure checking response headers.");
        }

        var page = testState.Page;

        // Intercept requests to inspect headers
        await page.RouteAsync("**/*", async route =>
        {
            var response = await route.FetchAsync();
            var headers = response.Headers;

            // Ensure the "server" header is either removed or is only reporting a generic "Web Server" value. 
            var serverHeader = headers.FirstOrDefault(h => string.Equals(h.Key, "Server", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            Assert.IsTrue(serverHeader.Value.IsNullOrEmpty() || serverHeader.Value == "Web Server", $"Server header not set correctly. Url: {response.Url}");

            // Continue checking header values

            await route.ContinueAsync();
        });
    }

    public void AfterTest(ITest test)
    {
    }

    public ActionTargets Targets => ActionTargets.Test;
}

[Test]
[CheckHeaders]
public async Task CheckHeaders()
{
    await Page.GotoAsync("mywebsite.com");
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
```

It seems that the issue is the FetchAsync call but I'm not seeing any other way to preconfigure header checks for every response another way.